# docker-compose resulted in The connection was reset (from firefox) or Empty reply from server (from curl)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo

I am using MX-Linux based on Debian buster (10). my docker engine info:

```
❯ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        831ebea
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 04:34:48 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       f001486
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 04:32:45 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

when I am trying to run `docker-compose up --build` against the following .yml file:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  odoo14:
    image: odoo:14
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    tty: true
    command: -- --dev=reload
    volumes:
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
    restart: always
```

it works fine as I see from logs however when I try to access the service **odoo14** from firefox I get an error `The connection was reset` & using curl I get an error `Empty reply from server`.

I checked other questions & they suggested to let the service **odoo14** to bind to address 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. so I replaced `command: -- --dev=reload` by `command: -- --http-interface=0.0.0.0` but with no success. even though it is mentioned in the [documentation that 0.0.0.0 is the default interface](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/cmdline.html#http).

I would like to let you know that I'm using dnsmasq to redirect anything `user.localhost:8069` or `a.user.localhost:8069` to localhost and it is working fine. but I'm not sure if it interferes with docker-compose or not.

when running the images using docker it is working fine. like using the following two commands:

```sh
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db postgres:13
docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo:14.0
```

I get redirected correctly in the browser. so what would be the problem of docker-compose?

### update

docker ps result

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                    NAMES
4a4dd3a0d7af        odoo:14             "/entrypoint.sh -- -…"   3 minutes ago       Up 5 seconds        8071-8072/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8069->8069/tcp   odoo-14-docker-compose_odoo14_1
5f2d64ea3374        postgres:13         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 7 seconds        5432/tcp                                 odoo-14-docker-compose_db_1
```

I guess it's networking problem because `netstat -nltp` result

```sh
netstat -nltp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39075         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      848/containerd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      755/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18540/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1124/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::8069                 :::*                    LISTEN      8984/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8071                 :::*                    LISTEN      8972/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      18540/cupsd
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using link on the command line. `--link db:db` .

But there are no network defined in your .yml.
define it with `networks:`

Comment: well, according  to docs (https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#links) Links also express implicit dependency between services in the same way as depends_on, so in the yml depends_on will make it. my problem isn't the link between service odoo14 and service db. it's between my browser & service odoo14. from logs I saw odoo14 connected to db

Comment: I also tried `network_mode: "host" ` in such case odoo14 fails to connect to db. so I'd try it again with `link` & I'll get back with the result.
thank you

Comment: Maybe try to use different external port